# Tableau ->Hbase connectivity [odbc driver]

Tags: odbc, hbase, tableau-api

I am trying to connect a Hbase table to Tableau for doing analytics directly on top of modelled data residing in Hbase (rather than tableau connecting to a more traditional RDBMS like MySql).

Can anyone point me to some ODBC drivers which I can use to do so. I tried Simba's ODBC driver but couldn't get very far, I am also looking for an open source alternative.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on how you couldn't get very far? The Simba driver should work, if it doesn't I can help you get there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Simba's HBase ODBC Driver. 
An overview of the same process I have written here : http://mydailyfindingsit.blogspot.in/2015/08/connect-hbase-in-hortonworks-and-tableau.html

Step 1 : Start the rest server in Hortonworks Linux machine

```
         /usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start rest -p 9768
```

Note: 9768 is port I have selected. make sure this port is free in your machine or else use a different port.

Step 2 : Download Simba ODBC Driver (in Windows Machine, where your tableau server is)

```
         http://www.simba.com/connectors/apache-hbase-odbc
```

Step 3 : Install it.

Step 4 :

Go to path highlighted in Yellow -> Add your Public Virtual IP ( you can get it from Azure VM -  Dashboard) . Enter port as used in command in step 1.

Step 5 : If you are using Azure , make sure in endpoints you have opened 9768 port.

Step 6 : Test the connection, it should show list of tables.

Step 7 : Connect with tableau using Other ODBC Connection. Select Simba as driver and provide Server.

Step 8 : If it doesn't work, make sure you have copied Simba licence file, which you received in email to the installed location. (C:\Program Files\Simba HBase ODBC Driver\lib)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to connect from Tableau to hbase data directly, but currently   Tableau supports connections to data stored in Cloudera's, Hortonworks', and MAPRdbs' HBase implementation through Hive ODBC driver.

You can find out more [here](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/hadoop-hive-connection) and [here](http://hortonworks.com/kb/how-to-connect-tableau-to-hortonworks-sandbox/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Simba HBase ODBC driver and try. I downloaded a trial and hadn't gone far enough. But, that is a possibility.

Nachi

Answer (score 0):

The Simba ODBC HBase driver works very well for me and I am currently using Tabeleau with it.

At what stage does yours fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Drill https://drill.apache.org/

Drill has a Hbase plug-in and query hbase CFs as relational queries

Tableau can connect to Drill